# How to I provide model to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here's my code :

```
        [HttpGet]
        public FileContentResult GetCalenderView()
        {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(this.ControllerContext, "GetCalenderView");
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, this.ViewData, this.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            var stringResult = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringResult);

            return File(byteArray, "application/octet-stream", "Month.xls");
        }
```

I found this online.
What this does is, gives me the view in string format and I send it as an excel file.
This is a strongly typed view.

My questions is, how do I provide model to this view ?

Comment: You return a View instead of a File?

Comment: Noooooooooooooo .. I want to return a file , but the view requires model data. how to I provide model data to view ?

Comment: You can't return a view and file from the same action method. So we need to know what actual data you want to return to the user - either a file, or HTML content? If it's both, then we can better come up with a solution, which may require JavaScript for example.

Comment: I am actually returning a view as an excel file. ..

Comment: yes.. but How to provide feed model data to View ?

Comment: you are returning a file. As stated above you can't return 2 different things from the same Action Method.

Comment: Looks like you're doing something badly wrong. Could you please add view code? Most probably there's more straightforward way to create Excel file than use an intermediary view.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev I am rendering a table in that view and not rendering it on the browser, instead I am serving it as an excel file as Microsoft excel can read html tables :) This gives me a good looking excel file and also saves me from using any third party tools to create excel file :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `Model` property of the ViewData that you're passing in.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FileContentResult GetCalenderView()
    {
        var viewData = ViewData; // Ideally copy this or make a fake of it
        viewData.Model = new object(); // Make this the model you want to pass in

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(this.ControllerContext, "GetCalenderView");
        // Note that we're passing in viewData instead of ViewData
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, viewData, this.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        var stringResult = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringResult);

        return File(byteArray, "application/octet-stream", "Month.xls");
    }
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Will put that in my utility belt for future use.